# QFileDialog - create files without an extension

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

I'd like to use the QFileDialog to get the name of a new directory, where I will create several configuration files.

It will be nice if a directory name will not contain an extension part. How can I force a user, to do not provide the QFileDialog with filename.extension?

I tried to use the following code:

```
QString fileName = 
    QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("create a directory), 
                                QDir::homePath(), tr("Directories (*)"));
```

But obviously it allows user to input any filename with or without an extension. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QFileDialog::GetExistingDirectory`

```
QString dir = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"), QDir::homePath(),
                                                QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
```

See the [QFileDialog Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory).

Comment: I tried to accent that it will be a "new" directory. User should provide the name and system will create directory with its content.

Comment: Don't think that's possible. The user should be able to create a directory with that dialog too. Why are you trying to force the user to create a new directory?

Comment: Cause for user it should be transparent. He just creates a new file (in some application specific format). But in fact it will be much easier for me to store it split into several files in one directory.

Comment: Well no idea then... Don't think that's possible with built in functions. Though I don't really think the transparency is necessary here, you could just have the user create a file and then implicitly save that as a directory. But that's your choice of course ;)